# Xcode 11.3 - xcodebuild - problem with signing - couldn't find provisioning

Tags: xcode, provisioning, signing

I am stuck on the problem of building a project from the command line.
I updated macOS from high sierra to Mojave.

Input data:

1. In Xcode, I see the necessary data in the Signing & Capabilities tab - Team, Bundle Identifier, Provisioning Profile, and Signing Certificate. All this is valid, the validity period has not expired.
2. In the Xcode => Preferences => Accounts settings, I see the account, I see the certificates.
3. In Keychain I see the required certificate, a private key is present.
4. The project from the Xcode itself is successfully assembled, does not swear at the provisioning profile.
5. Trying version Xcode: 10.1, 10.3, 11.3.

When I try to build a project from the command line with the command:

```
xcodebuild -project /Users/user/Documents/IOS/project.xcodeproj -configuration Release -xcconfig /Users/user/Documents/prov_appstore.xcconfig -scheme "iosproject" CODE_SIGN_STYLE = "Manual" clean archive -archivePath /Users/user/Documents/archive"
```

Then I get an error of the form:

> [BCEROR] Code Signing Error: No profile for team '' matching
>   'Project Distribution' found: Xcode couldn't find any provisioning
>   profiles matching ' / Project Distribution'. Install the
>   profile (by dragging and dropping it onto Xcode's dock item) or select
>   a different one in the Signing & Capabilities tab of the target
>   editor.

I tried to drag provisioning profiles into the project, tried to switch to Legacy, CODE_STYLE_SIGN removed - nothing helps.

What could be the reason? Why does Xcode compile fine through the interface, but doesn’t want to do it through the command line?

Thanks in advance!